# JW Player 7 no client-side analytics?

Tags: javascript, analytics, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

Forgive my lack of knowledge beforehand. I'm still learning the ins and outs of HLS.

Does the JW Player 7 API no longer offer client analytics? I noticed in this link from JW Player that the Current Bandwidth is always 0: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/toolbox/adaptive-streaming/

I'm just trying to get the basics: Average/Current Bandwidth, FPS, Dropped Frames, etc. I could probably workaround some of this if someone knows how to expose the XHR for video segments if anyone knows.

I did see that the API documentation says that metadata for bandwidth is only available for flash-hls. But my team is trying to discontinue use of flash.

Comment: You can try clappr with [clappr-stats](https://github.com/clappr/clappr-stats).